# String of Dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having a dictionary :-

`test_list = {"fname":"eoin","dob":"10/12/1992"}`

As this is just a sample dictionary but in my case the items of dictionary is dynamic it could be of any length. So I expect to create a string in this format

```
result = "fname : {fname} , dob: {dob}".format(**test_list)
```

As I would need this for my other purpose. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: `print(str(test_list).strip("{}"))` ?

Comment: No @creyD it's actually the oppostite that OP needs

Comment: What is not working with your current method? Do you only need to fname and dob in the result or you need everything?

Comment: @urban in this example i know the key name in my dictionary but when my dictionary is dynamic and it can have any number of key value pair where i don't know the name. How can i handle at that time. That was my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
print(str(test_list)[1:-1].replace("'", ""))
```

Output:

```
fname: eoin, dob: 10/12/1992
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple dict's string representation:

```
test_dict = {"fname":"eoin","dob":"10/12/1992","abc": 123}
res = ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k,v in test_dict.items())
print(res)
```

The output:

```
fname: eoin, dob: 10/12/1992, abc: 123
```

Comment: Seems like `.format(k, v)` should suffice. Also as a minor remark `join` is slightly faster when fed a list rather than a generator

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `str()` with `str.strip`

**Ex:**

```
test_dict = {"fname":"eoin","dob":"10/12/1992"}
print(str(test_dict).strip("{}").replace("'", "").replace('"', ""))
```

**Output:**

```
fname: eoin, dob: 10/12/1992
```

Comment: Sorry but this is the same answer as mine

Comment: @U10-Forward Almost similar...besides it was posted in the comments asking if OP required this solution

Comment: @Rakesh Oh yeah i see the difference